# How to uninstall malfunctioning extension in recovery mode?

Tags: 18.04, crash, gnome-shell-extension, recovery-mode, extension

I installed an extension called `IdleRPG` from the Ubuntu software center - which crashed my computer. Now, when I try to login, this extension crashes me back to the login page.

**How do I remove this extention in recovery mode?**

I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Please see my answer, and if it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the GRUB menu, boot into Recovery Mode, and get to the # prompt, then do:

`sudo rm -r /home/your_username/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/*IdleRPG*`

Comment: Thanks that did the trick